# Can I deploy automatically by AWS Elastic beanstalk and Code Commit?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I use Elastic Beanstalk. And it was connected with Code Commit.

I want that if I push to Code Commit repository, EB CLI or Code Commit automatically deploy this version to elasticbeanstalk

Can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script that periodically polls CodeCommit for new changes. When there is a new change, the script can trigger:

1. `git clone <codecommit repository>`
2. `eb init -p <platform name>`
3. `eb create`/`eb deploy`

of course, you probably don't need to clone every time, but this is basically how Jenkins works. In fact, you can just use Jenkins to poll CodeCommit. Any time there is a new commit detected, Jenkins will build it using the EBCLI.

Comment: Thanks! I’ll find that!!

Answer (score 0):

### CodePipeline

> AWS CodePipeline is a continuous delivery service you can use to model, visualize, and automate the steps required to release your software. You can quickly model and configure the different stages of a software release process. AWS CodePipeline automates the steps required to release your software changes continuously.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/welcome.html

Configure a pipeline with CodePipeline. When GitHub or CodeCommit is configured as the source stage, every single commit will trigger your pipeline to execute. When Beanstalk is configured as a deploy stage, it will automatically deploy whatever new code is going through the pipeline.

Comment: Wow!  many thanks to you! I'll try configuring this environment.